# Error using images2gif.py when resize animated GIF

Tags: python, image, resize, gif

I'm doing a project in which I have to resize animated GIF . I use Python and images2gif.py ([here](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/source/browse/vvmovie/images2gif.py)) . It works well with many images Gif but when I test with this image  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bKmT.gif)
an error occurs:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (96,100,4) (96,100,3)
```

My code here:

```
import Image
import images2gif

frames = images2gif.readGif("Images/image2.gif", False)

for frame in frames:
  frame.thumbnail((100,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

images2gif.writeGif('Images/image2out.gif', frames)
```

Comment: Can you try changing your second argument to True to use numpy arrays instead?

Comment: Hi, thanks your response. I changed second argument but an other error occurs: "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'thumbnail'"

Comment: I think that these errors are caused by space color of this image. Normally, image GIF use indexed color but this image use RGB ( I used Gimp to view the properties of image ). Solution: I try convert this image to indexed color, then I'll use code above in order to treat it. Other solutions are welcome !